# trying to redirect a user to a different link after an input was insert

Tags: php, html

I am learning PHP and HTML (sorry for being noob) trying to redirect a customers to a different link after an input was insert. which means after he press verify he will be redirect to my website www.example.com/home.php This is my current code:

```
    <div class="tclpad" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="tclpad"><input class="bstd" value="Verify" type="submit"></div>
```

Also, when someone inserts a wrong information, i can see in the code:

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['wrong'])) {
                echo "<p class='error'>Authentication failed.</p>";
                session_destroy();
            }
        ?>
```

I want the user after he press verify will get a message 'Verified'. 
Thank you so much guys for your help.

Comment: *"i can see in the code"* - What do you mean by that? It's literally showing "as code" or parsed as `Authentication failed.`?

Comment: I want them after press "verify" to be redirect. as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the accepted answer here: [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for with the 'Verified' statement, but the answer above shows how to redirect the web page with the PHP header() function.

Edit:
 I realized the header() function limits how the current page provides feedback. Instead, you could use javascript to redirect:

```
function redirectOnVerify(myVar) { 
    if(myVar === 'success'){
         window.alert('You have verified successfully');
         window.location = 'http://newlocation.com' ;              
    }
    else if (myVar === 'failure') {
          window.alert('Failed to verify');
    }
    else {
       console.log('PHP auth error, neither success nor failure')
    }
}
```

And then in your html:

```
<input onClick="redirectOnVerify('
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['right'])){ 
                   echo 'success'
                   }
                 else if (isset($_SESSION['wrong']){
                   echo 'failure'
                 }
                 else {}
            ?>
            ')">
```

/j

Comment: header("location: www.google.com"); this make me error

Comment: Have you tried prefacing it with http://  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use header() like

```
header("refersh: 2; url=page2url");
```

Refersh is a delay time here the page will redirect after 2 seconds if u don't want delay then either set refersh to 0 or do this

```
header("location=pag2url");
```

Comment: I want them after pressing verify they will be redirect.

Comment: header("location: www.google.com"); if i want to redirect the user to other website?

Comment: as per ur req i don't think u need to use php u can do this simply by a script like
    '<input class="bstd" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" value="Verify" type="submit">'